# How to create temporal table in rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, rspec

I have a model Address and one module Addressable injecting a *belongs_to :address* relation for AR classes which include this module Addressable.

I want to test that class that include this module have this relation.

class Address:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :street, :zip
end
```

module Addressable

```
module Addressable
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval <<-CLASS_METHODS
          belongs_to :address
          validates :address, presence: true
    CLASS_METHODS
  end
end
```

Test code:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'Addressable' do

  subject do
    class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
      include Addressable
    end
  end

  before(:all) do
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    connection.create_table :othermodels do |t|
      t.references :address
    end
  end

  after(:all) do
    connection.drop_table :othermodels
  end

  it "should validate presence of address"do
    should validate_presence_of(:address)
  end

  it "should belongs to address" do
should belong_to :continent
  end
end
```

My test fail with

```
 1) Addressable should validate presence of address
   Failure/Error: should validate_presence_of(:address)
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `address=' for OtherModel(Table doesn't exist):Class
```

I supose that the before(:all) is not doing it's work. How can I create this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the table name explicitly in the OtherModel definition to a table that exists in your model that has addressable.

```
table_name = "some table that exists with addressable columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Four years late, but I wanted to test a similar thing and found your question. I think you have everything right, except that the table should be called `other_models` by convention (your class is `OtherModel`).